# Fiddler generated certificate has invalid digital signature

Tags: fiddler, makecert, certenroll, fiddler-dev

Fiddler: v5.0.20182.28034 for .NET 4.6.1

Cert Generator: Tried both CertEnroll & MakeCert

Machine: Windows 10

Browser: Chrome

I have tried installing fresh fiddler also but no success. I even installed and reinstalled Fiddler Root Cert.

[image]

Comment: AFAIR Chrome has certain certificates (like *.google.com) pinned (CA pinning) by code which can't be changed. Therefore Fiddler won't work here ever if the cert would be trusted by your Windows.

Comment: You can try to export the certificate to a file and perform a detailed verification via `certutil.exe -verify <path to .cer file>`. May be the output of certutil.exe enlightens you why the cert is invalid.